# how to allow a hardcoded value between controller and action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to do them in a single call to MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default123",
                url: "{controller}/a1/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

How Can I combine the above calls into one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[Route("[controller]/a1/[action]")]
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    // .... your code
}
```

Comment: I have slightly modified my question.